# How to run process from chrome extension before computer sleeps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If a user sets their computer to sleep, how can I run a process from a chrome extension prior to the computer sleeping?

Comment: If chrome keeps extensions loaded when in chrome background-mode (browser closed but icon in taskbar), then you could perhaps detect when the extension page closes. Have a look at [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). But I'm not sure if chrome keeps extensions in memory.